# php curl CURLOPT_RESOLVE with HTTP Proxy

Tags: php, curl

How to make CURLOPT_RESOLVE working with Proxy added?
what i experienced if I put Proxy in my code, it will ignore CURLOPT_RESOLVE.

My code:

```
$ch = curl_init("https://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, "proxy.example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYPORT, "8080");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, "user:password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, 'HTTP');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RESOLVE, array('example.com:443:1.2.3.4'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'gzip, deflate, br');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0",
    "Referer: https://example.com"
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I already add curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_USE_GLOBAL_CACHE, false); code, but still not work.